# Batch hiding text from screen

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file like this.

```
echo hello world
```

But I get a long line of text before it can any one help.

I have looked on google but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now - if you were to tell us what the `long line of text` was, we wouldn't be left wondering what particular line of text of the billions of possibilities it was.

But in all probability, you need

```dos
@echo off
echo hello world
```

where the first command tells `cmd` to turn the echoing of each command off. The `@` tells `cmd` not to echo **that particular** command.

You could achieve the same result with

```dos
@echo hello world
```

but it's a real pain mechanically entering `@` before each command - hence the `@echo off` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@echo off` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Do ---->

@ECHO OFF

C:

CD\

CLS

:MENU

CLS

Echo HELLO WORLD!

Comment: Every line from `C:` to `:MENU` isn't needed.  CLS is optional but could be handy.